# Retrieve data from alternate column in SQL table

Tags: sql

I'm stuck on retrieving data from a table.

I am currently taking user input `$input` and where its equal to `station.station` name it outputs

Each station has an id, under the `station.station_id` column, and I would also like to so that when the station_id is lower than the id of the inputted station name, it displays

How would I compare the station id to the inputted station name?

Comment: please tag your database name .Also give sample of output for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, you can use this statement

```
select * from station where id < (select id from station where name=$input)
```